# My Macbook Pro says I'm connected to a power source even when unplugged

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have a Macbook Pro mid-2010 (Macbook 7,1) that is acting a bit weird. The battery status always says I'm connected to a power source even when the charger is unplugged. The battery still discharges, but the battery status says I'm connected to a power source. The exception is when I'm at the login screen, where the battery status displayed in the menu bar will be correct.

What I have tried to do:

- Done a clean install of Mavericks
- Reset SMC
- Reset PRAM
- Reinstalling the battery
- Using another charger
- Boot from my Macbook's original HDD

But to no avail.

Additional information: I just got my Macbook back from repair where they changed a faulty logic board. I have an Optibay installed where the CD-drive used to be and I have upgraded to 8 GB RAM. For the last 1-2 years I've been getting the "Service battery" in the battery status, but I have never had any issues with the battery before.

What do you think might be causing this, and how can I fix it?

(Screenshots taken while charger was unplugged). 
[image]
[image]

Comment: It came like that after logic board replacement? it did not do that before? The Service battery is Normal and nothing to worry about once you hit 30% below the Design capacity (your case). Once it shows Replace battery NOW then you act.

Comment: Try starting in safe mode to see if the problem is still there. Check the Middle pin (of the 5) for the magsafe plug and clean it.

Comment: Middle pin on the Magsafe on the charger or on the Macbook?

Comment: On the Macbook, since it shows it charging even if no charger is connected. That pin is responsible for that. Safe mode to eliminate 3d party apps.

Comment: The problem was not fixed by booting in safe mode. I tried cleaning the middle pin with a dry soft cloth, but to no avail..

Comment: We eliminated all others that makes the faulty logic board as end result. But just to be sure deactivate the Coconut battery app.

Comment: Damn, that's a letdown. I might have to get my Macbook repaired for a second time. As a full-time compsci student, being without a computer for weeks at a time is not optimal at all...

Comment: Are you sure your SMC reset worked? What is the color of the charging led on magsafe plug? When you do SMC reset while the magsafe is plugged in does the charging light changes shortly. Please publish your "pmset -g"

Comment: I don't know how to check if the SMC reset worked. I think it worked, but I'm not sure. The color of the charging led is orange when charging, and green when fully charged, as expected. 2-3 times today there has been no charging light on the Magsafe when plugged in, but the Macbook has still been charging.

Comment: pmset -g http://pastebin.com/Euar3vqU

Comment: sorry for not been clear, we need the pmset -g without power plugged in.

Comment: FYI----The SMC chip is mounted on the logic board.

Comment: pmset -g without power plugged in: http://pastebin.com/z4JTjjQV.

Comment: Bad news, that one shows you are still connected to the power! AC Power   2* (the asterisks indicates that). So where do you get the power from :)

Comment: It's not charging. It is discharging even though it says it is connected to power. I have no idea why this is happening. The weird thing is that the battery status is correct on the login screen, but not past that.

Comment: That is weird indeed. Did you actually boot in Safe mode, or try to log in as different user.

Comment: Note that processes may dynamically override these power management settings by using I/O Kit power assertions.  Whenever processes override any system power settings, pmset will list those processes and their power assertions in -g and -g assertions  ....so run "pmset -g assertions" to check on that

Comment: I did actually boot into safe mode, and I have also tried to boot into my original Macbook HDD as opposed to my SSD. Same problem. pmset -g assertions: http://pastebin.com/GE8C2ckX

Comment: Thank you, sorry to inform you there is nothing there that would be doing that. What it is strange you claiming it works fine until you log in.

Comment: Yes, I don't really understand it. And just now, after the battery was fully charged, I unplugged the charger and went to the login screen, and the battery status was **INCORRECT**. But when I rebooted it was **correct** again. So I don't really know what to make of it. It seems like a hardware issue. I guess the technicians messed something up during the repair or something like that, so I'll need to take in for another repair... Anyway, thank you very much for taking the time to try to sort out the issue, even though a solution wasn't discovered.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i fixed mine. I went to "energy saver preferences" in "system preferences", and went to "power adapter" at the top, then i clicked "show battery status in menu" option off then on again and that seemed to work for me.

Hope this helps!