# MacBook shows Power Source as Power Adapter even when unplugged

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

Similar old questions:

[MacBook Air shows battery as power source when plugged in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319497/macbook-air-shows-battery-as-power-source-when-plugged-in)

[MacBook Pro: Battery icon shows as charging even when not connected to power source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362841/macbook-pro-battery-icon-shows-as-charging-even-when-not-connected-to-power-sou)

[My Macbook Pro says I'm connected to a power source even when unplugged](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177563/my-macbook-pro-says-im-connected-to-a-power-source-even-when-unplugged)

SMC reset didn't work for me, and turning the option off and on again didn't help either.

I am using a 15" 2018 MacBook Pro.

The sensor doesn't seem to be damaged as suggested in one of the answers as I can see some difference in reading when disconnected and connected back to the charger -

Charging:
[image]

Not charging:
[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Since the laptop is assuming that it's connected to a power source, I feel that the battery is depleting faster than expected.

Update: I have observed that when I remove the plug it shows me the "charging" status for some time (3-4 minutes) and then switches to "not charging but plugged in" status. Further, I don't get the sound which denotes the charger is plugged in when I plug it.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue once, SMC reset didn't help neither nor turning the option off and on again...

What I did was:

- I turned off my MBP without beeing connected to a power source
- I connected it and waited until the charging logo appear
- I turned it on still connected

After that, it came back to normal

(I noticed this bug when I was looking at the *istat menu* battery log while pluggin/unpluggin the power source)

Comment: This didn't work for me :(

Comment: How could the "charging logo" appear (2d bullet point) if the MBP is still turned off?

Comment: Well, I don't know, but when I plug my MBP when he's off a logo appear shortly after the plugging sound and show the % of battery level

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2023 MBP connected to the Apple Studio Display.  I notice that if the Display is connected but power adapter is not, the battery icon indicated power adapter connected.  If I disconnect the Display and open the MBP, then the battery icon indicates running on battery.  If I connect the power adapter, MBP indicates power adapter.  So, only if the Display is connected does the battery indicator provide incorrect power status.

But I figured it out.  I don't need the power adapter when I'm using the Display.  The Display has it's own power and it will also power the MBP. So the battery icon is correct when I'm using the display or using the MBP on its own.